# Entity Framework with mysql, entity without PK

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am using EF with MySQL for external database (database from other project that just connected to mine). So I can't change database structure.

The Database have some tables without PK, but if I am right EF entity should have primary key.

I think that I will not have any problems with just reading the table, I just add Key attribute for any filled in entity. But what if I need to add row to that table with same value on OK? I will get error that PK with same value already exists...

I need any help or suggestions how to work with that tabale. Thanks in advance

Comment: JFYI Your profile shows that you haven't used your privilege to [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) yet. You can upvote useful answers and questions. Also when you [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647) an answer it's reasonable to upvote the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark all columns as part of PK and read entities in No Tracking mode:

```
var data = db.TheTable.Where(...).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

If you need to add new row with same values - this is OK unless you already have same row in you database context. With No Tracking mode this can happens only if you add **two** rows with same values.

Workaround: add rows in separate operations, detach entities after SaveChanges:

```
var row = ...;
db.TheTable.Add(row);
db.SaveChanges();
db.Entry(row).State = EntityState.Detached;
// now you can add the row again
```

If you need to delete untracked row - you must attach it first:

```
var row = ...;
db.TheTable.Attach(row);
db.TheTable.Remove(row);
db.SaveChanges();
db.Entry(row).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Or you can manually change row state:

```
var row = ...;
db.Entry(row).State = EntityState.Deleted;
db.SaveChanges();
db.Entry(row).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

But i does not know haow many rows will be deleted if you try to delete row with duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Every table **must** have a Primary Key. I don't know if you can change the schema but, a solution would be to add an autoincremental Primary Key on these tables and use that new column as the Entity Framework Key too.

This way, you could insert rows with the same values and at the same time you'd have a unique row identifier. Adding every column to the primary key constraint is an ugly workaround.

Comment: yes, i know it, but i can't change database schema :(

Comment: Then you will need to write SQL because every Entity Framework entity needs a Key. Or ask for permission to modify the database schema if you want to work with entities. To write SQL you can use the Entity Framework methods https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx. Obviously, you lose some of the power of Entity Framework but you can still inflate objects from the query result.